# Change the value of an attribute in Sequelize automatically after a certain period of time using Typescript

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js

I have two Sequelize models in SQLite as follows:

`Service(serviceId, serviceName, price, availabilityStatus)`

`Purchase(purchaseId, serviceId(FK), buyingUser, quantity, dateOfPurchase, serviceDuration)`

I wanted to buy a service for a period of time. So, when booking a service from the post method, a record is inserted into the `Purchase` model, with the duration of the service as `serviceDuration` in hours or days. Also, the 'availabilityStatus' in `Service` model is changed to 'notAvailable'.

I now wanted a way to change automatically the `availabilityStatus` to 'available' from 'notAvailable' after the specified `serviceDuration` is completed.

Can somebody help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use cron for this https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron